# Flutter - How to play a sequence of videos one after another?

Tags: flutter, dart, video

How can I play a sequence of videos one after another with no breaks in between and no user action - just show videos one right after the other? (efficiently)

Here is what I tried:

VideoPlayer:

```
class MyVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  MyVideoPlayer({
    Key? key,
    required this.onComplete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  @override
  MyVideoPlayerState createState() => MyVideoPlayerState();
}
class MyVideoPlayerState extends State<MyVideoPlayer> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (!controller.value.isPlaying &&
          controller.value.position.inSeconds >=
              controller.value.duration.inSeconds) {
        widget.onComplete();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VideoPlayer(
      controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyVideoPlayer(
        onComplete: () {
          _playVideo(asset);
        },
      );
  }
}

 _playVideo(String asset) {
    controller =
        VideoPlayerController.asset(asset);

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    
        if (!controller.value.isPlaying &&
            controller.value.position.inSeconds >=
                controller.value.duration.inSeconds) {
        
        }
    
    });
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
     controller.play();
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });
    setState(() {
    
    });
  }
```

But `onComplete` gets accessed only after the first video and then no more. It should be called after each video is finished.

Any way of solving this will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can play multiple video by creating list of videos at initstate or in seperate datamodel and then changing the index of list to the controller.

this method also have some issue as mentioned in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616435/videocontroller-used-after-being-disposed-error-in-flutter-video-player)

```
void playVideo() async {
    if (DateTime.now().isAfter(videoData[index].start_from) &&
        DateTime.now().isBefore(videoData[index].end_on)) {
      bool played_count = await CountQuery().whenComplete(() {
        
      });
      
      file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
      if (file.existsSync() && !played_count) {
        isEnd = true;

        controller = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
          ..initialize().then((value) {
            setState(() {
              controller.play();
            });

            controller.addListener(() {

              // checking the duration and position every time
              // Video Completed//

              if (controller.value.duration == controller.value.position &&
                  isEnd) {
                setState(() {
                  isEnd = false;
                });
                CreateLog("video");                         
                controller.dispose();
                PlayNext();
                
              }
            });
          })
          ..setLooping(false);
      } else {
        PlayNext();
      }
    } else {
      PlayNext();
    }
  }

  void PlayNext() {
    setState(() {
      index++;
    
      if (videoData.length > index) {
        // this.asset = videoData[index].file_link;
        this.file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
        playVideo();
      } else {
        index = 0;
        // this.asset = videoData[index].file_link;
        this.file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
        playVideo();
      }
    });
  }
```