# videoController used after being disposed error in flutter video_player

Tags: flutter, video, dispose, sequential

I am building a videoplayer application in Flutter that plays multiple videos one by one by fetching from the database

After completion of one video we need to transfer videocontroller to another video so first I dispose video controller and initialize with another video

It works fine for 4,5 video sequence and then throw a error like this

```
throw FlutterError(
          'A $runtimeType was used after being disposed.\n'
          'Once you have called dispose() on a $runtimeType, it can no longer be used.',
        );
```

Part of my code throwing this error is

```
void playVideo() async {
    if (DateTime.now().isAfter(videoData[index].start_from) &&
        DateTime.now().isBefore(videoData[index].end_on)) {
      bool played_count = await CountQuery().whenComplete(() {
        
      });
      
      file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
      if (file.existsSync() && !played_count) {
        isEnd = true;

        controller = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
          ..initialize().then((value) {
            setState(() {
              controller.play();
            });

            controller.addListener(() {

              // checking the duration and position every time
              // Video Completed//

              if (controller.value.duration == controller.value.position &&
                  isEnd) {
                setState(() {
                  isEnd = false;
                });
                CreateLog("video");                         
                controller.dispose();
                PlayNext();
                
              }
            });
          })
          ..setLooping(false);
      } else {
        PlayNext();
      }
    } else {
      PlayNext();
    }
  }

  void PlayNext() {
    setState(() {
      index++;
    
      if (videoData.length > index) {
        // this.asset = videoData[index].file_link;
        this.file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
        playVideo();
      } else {
        index = 0;
        // this.asset = videoData[index].file_link;
        this.file = File(videoData[index].file_link);
        playVideo();
      }
    });
  }
```

Note: I am using video_player: ^2.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding `controller = null` after each dispose